# Clarification on justification for fixed-point iteration

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I'm trying to understand why fixed-point iteration works. I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/721497/749638) answer by user "JiK":

> Let us assume that function $g$ is defined on an interval $(a,b)$, $g(x)\in(a,b)$ in that interval, and that there is a constant $c<1$ such that for each $x,y \in (a,b)$,
>   \begin{equation}
> \left|g(y)-g(x)\right| < c |x-y|. \tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>   If $g$ has a derivative, this becomes $g'(x)<c$ for $x\in(a,b)$.
>
> The fixed point iteration is defined by $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$, where $x_0$ is an arbitrarily chosen starting point in $(a,b)$.
>
> Let us assume that the function has a fixed point at $\hat{x}\in(a,b)$, that is $\hat{x}=g(\hat{x})$.
>
> Now at step $k$, the absolute error of our current guess to the fixed point is $e_k = |x_k-\hat{x}|$. We get
>   $$
> e_{k+1} = |x_{k+1}-\hat{x}| = |g(x_k)-g(\hat{x})| < c|x_k - \hat{x}| = c e_k.
> $$
>
> Therefore, the sequence $(e_k)_k$ is nonnegative and bounded above by the sequence $(c^ke_0)_k$, which converges to $0$. Therefore, $\lim_{k\to\infty}e_k=0$. This means that the fixed point iteration converges to $\hat{x}$.
>
> ---
>
> For general $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we can make following observations:
>
> If (1) holds in $\mathbb{R}$, we can replace $(a,b)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ in the above proof. One can also see that the function has exactly one fixed point in that case (if $g$ is differentiable, the derivative of $g(x)-x$ is smaller than a negative constant, thus $g(x)-x$ has exactly one zero; if $g$ is not differentiable, a similar argument still holds).
>
> If (1) does not hold in $\mathbb{R}$ but holds in an interval $(a,b)$ containing a fixed point, we can see that $g(a)>a$ and $g(b)<b$, so $g(x) \in (a,b)$ as required. Now the fixed point iteration converges to the fixed point if $x_0$ is chosen inside the interval.

I'm having difficulty understanding a couple of things here:

1. This all depends on there existing a constant $c<1$ such that for each $x,y \in (a,b)$,
   \begin{equation}
   \left|g(y)-g(x)\right| < c |x-y|. \tag{1}
   \end{equation}
   But what is the justification for this (that is, how do we know that this is a valid assumption)? In response to user "copper.hat"'s comment, how do we check that this is valid for any particular situation? Is there a theorem that we can apply to a situation that allows us to conclude that this is true (perhaps some theorem about differentiability or something)?
2. Where did the $c^k$ in $(c^ke_0)_k$ come from?

Can someone please help me understand this? Thank you.

Comment: It is an assumption. It is something that would need to be checked in a particular application. If $e_{n_1} \le c e_n$ then $e_n \le e_oc^n$.

Comment: @copper.hat But how do we check it for any particular situation? Is there something about differentiability or something that allows us to conclude that this is true? Is there a theorem involved here? I would like more clarity on this. I think your representation of the second point clears it up for me. Thanks.

Comment: If the absolute value of the derivative is bounded above by $c<1$ then you can conclude that it is true, for example.

Comment: @copper.hat So if there exists some $c < 1$ such that $\vert g'(x) \vert < c$?

Comment: Most commonly this only all works near the fixed point: specifically if $g$ is continuously differentiable, $g(x_0)=x_0$ and $|g'(x_0)|<1$ then $g$ is contractive on some neighborhood of $x_0$, without the need to explicitly check that it maps a domain into itself. Generally we engineer $|g'(x_0)|<1$, for example in the fixed point iteration that defines Newton's method at a simple zero, you have $g'(x_0)=0$ by construction.

Comment: @Ian Ok, thanks! As an aside: What does "contractive" mean?

Comment: $g$ being contractive on some domain means there exists $c<1$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|<c|x-y|$ for every $x,y$ in that domain.